# Retrieve all folders using root (su) in ADB

Tags: android, adb, root, su

How do I retrieve all folders using su in one command?
Without root I use

```
adb shell "ls -R / | grep /"
```

And when I try

```
adb shell su "ls -R / | grep /"
```

it doesn't work.
How must the syntax be to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-c` option of `su` to execute a command.  You also need two levels of quotes --

```
adb shell "su -c 'ls -R / | grep /'"
```